# ObjectMapper readValue Fail

Tags: java

I want to make a UserUtil to auto make User and get the User's mobile and cookie in the txt file.
I finished auto insert the User's information into the mysql,but I can't auto write it into the txt file.
The main code about this:

```
public class UserUtil {
    private static void createUser(int count) throws Exception {
        // the code about insert into database not show here

        // login,get the cookie
        String urlString = "http://localhost:8080/login/toLogin";
        File file = new File("my file location");
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        raf.seek(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            User user = users.get(i);
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream out = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            String params = "mobile=" + user.getId() + "&password=" + MD5Util.inputPassToFormPass("123456");

            // the params I test show the first line in database,such as mobile=1300000000&password=d3b1294a61a07da9b49b6e22b2cbd7f9
            System.out.println(params); 

            out.write(params.getBytes());
            out.flush();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buff)) >= 0) {
                bout.write(buff, 0, len);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            bout.close();
            String response = new String(bout.toByteArray
            // I test the response print my login.html content
            System.out.println(response); 
 
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            RespBean respBean = mapper.readValue(response,RespBean.class);
            String userCookie = ((String) respBean.getObj());
            System.out.println("create userCookie : " + user.getId());
            String row = user.getId() + "," + userCookie;
            raf.seek(raf.length());
            raf.write(row.getBytes());
            raf.write("\r\n".getBytes());
            System.out.println("write to file :" + user.getId());
        }
        raf.close();
        System.out.println("over");
    }
}
```

I run it , the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>login</title>
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <!-- jquery-validator -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-validation/jquery.validate"[truncated 2917 chars]; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1851)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:707)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:632)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1947)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:776)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4664)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4513)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3468)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3436)
    at com.example.demo.utils.UserUtil.createUser(UserUtil.java:85)
    at com.example.demo.utils.UserUtil.main(UserUtil.java:108)
```

the UserUtil.java:85 is this line:
RespBean respBean = mapper.readValue(response,RespBean.class);

my RespBean :

```
package com.example.demo.vo;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RespBean {
    private  long code;
    private String message;
    private Object obj;

    /**
     * Success
     * @return
     */
    private static RespBean success(){
        return new RespBean(RespBeanEnum.SUCCESS.getCode(),RespBeanEnum.SUCCESS.getMessage(),null);
    }
    public static RespBean success(Object obj){
        return new RespBean(RespBeanEnum.SUCCESS.getCode(),RespBeanEnum.SUCCESS.getMessage(),obj);
    }

    /**
     * Fail
     * @param respBeanEnum
     * @return
     */
    public static RespBean error(RespBeanEnum respBeanEnum){
        return new RespBean(respBeanEnum.getCode(),respBeanEnum.getMessage(),null);
    }

    public static RespBean error(RespBeanEnum respBeanEnum,Object obj){
        return new RespBean(respBeanEnum.getCode(),respBeanEnum.getMessage(),obj);
    }

}
```

the RespBeanEnum:

```
@Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum RespBeanEnum {
    // All
    SUCCESS(200,"SUCCESS"),
    ERROR(500,"Server error"),
    // Login part
    LOGIN_ERROR(500210,"username or password error"),
    MOBILE_ERROR(500211,"mobile layout error"),
    BIND_ERROR(500212,"parameter error"),
    ;
    private final Integer code;
    private final String message;
}
```

and my UserServiceImpl return is no problem

```
public RespBean doLogin(LoginVo loginVo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // the login logic code don't show here
    // the UUIDUtil is the util to make the cookie
    String uuid = UUIDUtil.uuid();
    CookieUtil.setCookie(request,response,"userCookie",uuid);
    return RespBean.success(uuid);
}
```

Comment: I search all the night , many people meet the question is their json translate problem, their error information isn't similat to mine. My error show the html languaue, I feel uncertain,I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get the cookie you can use the http connection through the Java API. Don't need to deserialize the HTML page. The error you see it's because you try to deserialize an HTML string as a JSON.

Comment: I am very sorry to ask this foolish question, I find my problem this morning. It's because I wrote wrong about the urlString... The true is "http://localhost:8080/login/doLogin" ,but I wrote "http://localhost:8080/login/toLogin"... So I can't get what I want to get... So,the code about get the cookie is no problem,just my low level error!